# Why is it when I'm downloading my array and try to get the length of it, it just spits out the number of bytes the array is

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When I use the jQuery library to download an array and get the length of it using native javascript, it just spits out the total amount of bytes of the array, like so:

```js
$.get({
  url: 'https://rawgit.com/tvman-123/shrek/master/ExampleOutputForSubscription_Post.php', //
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    ParseData(data);
  }
});


function ParseData(data) {
  console.log(data.length) //Returns 221
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

But when I include the array inline, it works like it's supposed to, like so:

```js
data=["UU9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ","UUrTNhL_yO3tPTdQ5XgmmWjA","UUz-RZblnhjXK_krP1jDybeQ","UUc_xdkOBgSYLmXTn-VSQ4uA","UUmb8hO2ilV9vRa8cilis88A","UU45SDrjKlPSY0bTvH6F7TOA","UUdGkmb5zEDXnPSmQlV43t0Q","UUpeGBKn0axOJAcPHkcPiXcg",""]
ParseData(data)

function ParseData(data){
console.log(data.length)//Returns 9
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

My understanding is that the first one is a byte array and the second one is an arraylist.

Can someone please explain to me why its doing this and how to fix it???

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your answers, and helping me fix this problem

Comment: When data is retrieved from a request it always comes in as a stream of bytes (a string in this case). It does not come pre-parsed into an array for you.

Comment: When arrays are transferred from an API, they are usually transferred as JSON, (a string notation for objects). You will need to first parse the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type of data received is JSON!
add  **dataType: "json"**

```js
$.get({
  url: 'https://rawgit.com/tvman-123/shrek/master/ExampleOutputForSubscription_Post.php', //
  data: {},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.length); // data is parsed.. =)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When a response comes from the server, it's generally in the form of bytes, (JSON in this case). This is no longer an array in the true sense, it's more like a string.

You need to convert the JSON into an array first. Only then you will be able to find its true length.

You have forgotten to parse the JSON in the first case. You should use [`JSON.parse(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) first and then see the array length.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `JSON.parse` because it comes in as a stream of bytes (string in this case).

```js
$.get({
  url: 'https://rawgit.com/tvman-123/shrek/master/ExampleOutputForSubscription_Post.php', //
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
    ParseData(JSON.parse(data));
  }
});


function ParseData(data) {
  console.log(data.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ***Array*** and ***String*** objects provide their ***length*** property.
What you are reading is the length of a string you've retrieved. Not of an Array object, because objects cannot travel through Internet.

What you now have in your data variable, is a string representation of the array code. Which in order to be used as a real Array object, needs to be first *evaluated* to an *object* using (now widely supported) ***JSON*** api ***parse*** method. Then you will be able to get the length of an array instead of the string length.